# Get UICollectionView cell position after scrollToItemAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, uikit, uicollectionview

I would like to get a `UICollectionViewCell`'s position after programattically scrolling to a cell.  I'm setting the scroll position like this.

```
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath
                             atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically
                                        animated:NO];
```

I would then like to get the frame of the cell I have scrolled to as I need to position another `UIView` near it.

This code returns the rect of the cell with the scrollview, but I need the position within the visible rect.

```
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [self.collectionView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
CGRect cellRect = attributes.frame;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The frame of a cell doesn't change, it's the content offset of the enclosing scroll view. Subtract the `contentOffset` from the frame's origin to get the on-screen position, or use one of the `convertRect:` methods to get the coordinates in a related view.

Comment: Thanks.  Alternatively would there be a way to get a reference to this cell immediately after setting the scroll position?  cellforitematindexpath returns nil at this point.

Comment: It's returning nil because the cell isn't on screen at the time. Your existing solution is probably fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the cell X and Center values

```
UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *attributes = [collectionView layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
CGPoint cellCenterPoint = attributes.center;
CGPoint contentOffset = [collectionView contentOffset];
NSLog(@"%f  , %f",-1*contentOffset.x , cellCenterPoint.x);
int  relativeCellCenter = (-1*contentOffset.x) + cellCenterPoint.x +collectionView.frame.origin.x;
int relativeX = (-1*contentOffset.x) +collectionView.frame.origin.x;
```